# Accessing SVN Server remotely

Tags: router, dns, apache-http-server, svn, port-forwarding

So here I'm after investing days of effort into it. I have SVN Apache Edge running on my machine on top of Apache. I want to access it (check-out/check-in) from a remote machine. My machine is behind a normal router and has a dynamic IP. Here's what I have achieved:

1. Registered my machine using a DDNS service and got a URL.
2. Enabled port forwarding (port 8085 forwarded to my machine's port 80) on the router.
3. I'm pretty sure SVN/Apache are listening on port 80, becuz I can type `http://localhost` in the browser (on my machine) and get a list of repo directories.
4. But when I type `http://My_DDNS_URL:8085` on a remote machine, it takes almost forever waiting for a response from my machine and ends up in time-out (I think).
5. I can ping both my dynamic IP address as well as my URL (assigned by DDNS service) from the remote machine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is port 8085 being forwarded through the router to the target server?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using SVN? Mercurial, Git etc. are good pieces of software and are easier to share changes whether using a free hosted service or running a server yourself.

Comment: I have been working with SVN for quite some time now. Switching to another versioning system may involve some learning curve, which I want to avoid at this point in my running project's schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be in one of several places. The three most likely are:

- Apache is *only* [listening on localhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html) (instead of, say, `192.168.1.x` or `0.0.0.0`)
- The port-forwarding isn't working/setup properly (e.g. port `8085` is forwarded to `192.168.1.12` yet your PC has changed to `192.168.1.14` since it last rebooted)
- Your modem/router is not doing [NAT-loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) (normally if you want to access your service from inside your network you connect to `http://192.168.1.x` and if you are outside you use `http://1.2.3.4` -- NAT-loopback redirects requests from *inside* the network to its external address back into its internal address [e.g. to `1.2.3.4` into `192.168.1.x`] (so the external address still works internally).

Comment: Thanks. I also found that I can do  `http://My_DDNS_URL` (without the port number) from the remote machine and that would take me to the router's home page (the same page that I can access by typing 192.168.1.1 on my local machine). Does that help in eliminating any of the above possibilities?

Comment: It sounds as if there is no NAT-loopback feature on your router (or it isn't enabled). From what I understand it is __not__ very common. The easiest way to check is to get somebody outside your network to connect -- if they can (and you can't) then it's NAT-loopback issue. NAT-loopback is more of a convenience feature; really you should be connecting to localhost (or whatever IP/hostname your computer has) when you are inside your network.

Comment: As a very basic test, if you don't have access to a server or computer on an outside network, you can go to something like [ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2), enter the external port number (i.e. 8085) and click `User Specified Custom Port Probe`. It won't tell you _what_ is listening (i.e. Apache) but it will tell you if outside people can connect

Comment: ShieldsUP! tells me that my port 8085's status is OPEN with unknown protocol/application. How does that help?

Comment: I have also confirmed by reading the conf file of Apache server that it is listening on port 80 on all interfaces (by comparing it to the doc link you provided above). So #1 is not the issue here.

Comment: #2 is also not a problem here. I'm using static IP in my LAN configuration and port forwarding is configured against that IP in the router.

Comment: Got it working. It is apparently becuz of #3 above. I can access my repos from outside, but not inside the network. So I guess my router doesn't support NAT-loopback. I'll mark this as answer.